# Is it good to use like this?

Tags: c, string

```
char str[50];
memset(str,0,50);
strcpy(str,"beauty");
char *name = str;
```

1) Can we assign char * = char [ ] like above. 
2) Is there a possibility of something can go wrong if we pass this name as a parameter to some other function?

Comment: You don't need to clear `str` since `strcpy` also copies the end NUL byte.

Comment: Note: Rather than repeating 50 twice, consider `memset(str,0,sizeof str);`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do that, but note that `name` will point to `str`, so if you modify the characters that name points to you'll also modify `str` (and vice-versa).

If you want `name` to be a copy of `str`, so that you can modify it independently, then you should allocate enough memory in name and use strcpy or memcpy.